# Force each select in group to have a unique value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

I have a group of 6 dropdowns (select elements) that each have the same 6 options.  What I want, is that when an option is selected in a dropdown it is removed from all the others.  Then, if that dropdown has it's value changed, the selected option should be re-added to each of the other dropdowns.

My HTML contains 6 dropdowns like below:

```
<select>
    <option>Strength</option>
    <option>Dexterity</option>
    <option>Constitution</option>
    <option>Intelligence</option>
    <option>Wisdom</option>
    <option>Charisma</option>
</select>
```

So if the user selects 'Strength' in one dropdown, it should be removed from the other dropdowns, and then if the user changes that dropdown to 'Dexterity', the other dropdowns should have 'Srrength' re-added.

Comment: Such a question can't let others know how to help you. You can put the main or code you think is problematic into the description.

Answer (score 0):

Run the snippet below.

What's happening is that we're attaching an onchange event to the class; selectGroup.
This onchange event will loop through all the options belonging to all selectGroups and will hide the matching value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // attach event to all with selectGroup class
  $(".selectGroup").change(function() {

    // store selected value to variable
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    // loop through select > options, show all the previously hidden
    $(".selectGroup").each(function() {
      $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
      })
    });

    // loop through select > options, hide matching value
    $(".selectGroup").each(function() {
      $(this).find("option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == selectedValue) {
          $(this).hide();
        }
      })
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selectGroup {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>1st</label>
<select class="selectGroup">
  <option>Strength</option>
  <option>Dexterity</option>
  <option>Constitution</option>
  <option>Intelligence</option>
  <option>Wisdom</option>
  <option>Charisma</option>
</select>

<label>2nd</label>
<select class="selectGroup">
  <option>Strength</option>
  <option>Dexterity</option>
  <option>Constitution</option>
  <option>Intelligence</option>
  <option>Wisdom</option>
  <option>Charisma</option>
</select>

<label>3rd</label>
<select class="selectGroup">
  <option>Strength</option>
  <option>Dexterity</option>
  <option>Constitution</option>
  <option>Intelligence</option>
  <option>Wisdom</option>
  <option>Charisma</option>
</select>

<label>4th</label>
<select class="selectGroup">
  <option>Strength</option>
  <option>Dexterity</option>
  <option>Constitution</option>
  <option>Intelligence</option>
  <option>Wisdom</option>
  <option>Charisma</option>
</select>

<label>5th</label>
<select class="selectGroup">
  <option>Strength</option>
  <option>Dexterity</option>
  <option>Constitution</option>
  <option>Intelligence</option>
  <option>Wisdom</option>
  <option>Charisma</option>
</select>

<label>6th</label>
<select class="selectGroup">
  <option>Strength</option>
  <option>Dexterity</option>
  <option>Constitution</option>
  <option>Intelligence</option>
  <option>Wisdom</option>
  <option>Charisma</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```